# Mercurial don't find editor in my path

Tags: mercurialeclipse

i'm becoming crazy..
Ever the same error,can't find editor notepad in my path,using mercurial by eclipse.
But in my path there is the directory of notepad.
How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This might be the same as: [Mercurial Eclipse Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989660/mercurial-eclipse-error)

Usually this is caused by your PATH environment variable being somehow corrupted and can be fixed by making a single character change to it, pressing ok, then reverting the change.