# error in installing mercurial plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, eclipse-plugin, mercurialeclipse

I just installed a mercurial plugin for eclipse. The installation process went well. But after installing when I restarted eclipse an error was shown.

The error says:

> Multiple Mercurial errors have occurred. 
>   Please check the Error Log view for detailed information.
>   . Command line: hg -y debuginstall

I can't find any possible solution for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try running `hg -y debuginstall` from the command line. It should show something like that:

```
Checking encoding (cp1252)...
Checking installed modules (D:\Kazan\mercurial\library.zip\mercurial)...
Checking templates...
Checking commit editor...
Checking username...
No problems detected
```

If it doesn't, it should give you an indication on what's the problem.
If the command is not found, install mercurial from https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download or install tortoise-hg from http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/

Comment: Use "Window + R" to open the run dialog, run "cmd.exe" to open a terminal, and write the command there.

Comment: After installing tortoisehg, I still had to go to Window->Preferences->Team->Mercurial and browse to the hg.exe executable that was installed with tortoisehg.

Comment: @scawf your approach requires installation of an extra Mercurial client (tortoisehg) which is not required for the plugin to work, just the core mercurial installation that comes bundled with it is needed. Just installing Mercurial alone from [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download) would have done the trick.

Comment: After having specified the hg.exe path in Window->Preferences->Team->Mercurial (as suggested by Rick) I had to *reimport* my Mercurial project in the workspace.

Answer (score 3):

The plugin, is just a user interface and uses the underlying **Mercurial** installation.

This error occurs primarily when **Mercurial Plugin for Eclipse** is installed without actually installing **Mercurial** earlier on your system.

To solve this problem, first:

1. Install **Mercurial** on your system using one of the installers that best suits you from
   [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download).
2. Go to Window->Preferences->Team->Mercurial and in **mercurial executable** field, browse to the:

> hg.exe

executable that was installed with the mercurial installation above.

Mercurial Plugin for Eclipse will work just fine now.

Comment: @scawf This approach does not require installation of TortoiseHG which adds an extraneous Mercurial Client to the system in addition to the Mercurial install which is not needed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

i have found the same problem... seems my update of the Nvidia driver deletes all my variables environments and `Mercurial can find the notepad.exe` i found the solution adding in the `mercurial.ini` locate in **Users** folder adding the path to `notepad.exe` directly.

```
[ui]
username=myusername
editor = c:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe
ignore=....
```

i have found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989660/mercurial-eclipse-error)

i hope helps somebody

Answer (score 0):

Best solution which I found:

1. Install `eclipse Juno`.
2. Goto: `help -> eclipse` `marketplace -> enter` `'mercurial'` and do a `search`, select first option of mercurial.
3. Then go to `Windows -> Preferences -> Team -> Mercurial` select and copy path from `Mercurial Executable`.
   Now open your previous `eclipse (Luna or mars)`.
4. Go to same path. `Windows -> Preferences -> Team -> Mercurial`and paste that path in `Mercurial` Executable.  Now it will work.