# mercurial plugin in eclipse- Cannot satisfy dependency Error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mercurialeclipse

I am facing below issue while trying to install mercurialEclipse plugin using below site via install new software of Eclipse.

mercurial site - https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/update-site/raw/default/

Eclipse version- Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

```
    Error - Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
    Software currently installed: MercurialEclipse 2.5.2.201806082050 (mercurialeclipse.feature.group 2.5.2.201806082050)
    Missing requirement: MercurialEclipse 2.5.2.201806082050 (com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse 2.5.2.201806082050) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jface.text 3.11.0' but it could not be found
    Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: MercurialEclipse 2.5.2.201806082050 (mercurialeclipse.feature.group 2.5.2.201806082050)
    To: com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse [2.5.2.201806082050]
```

Please help me resolve it.

Also note that I already have TortoiseHg installed on my system. And I have already taken help from below links without any luck-

[error in installing mercurial plugin for eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089918/error-in-installing-mercurial-plugin-for-eclipse)

[Mercurial Eclipse Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629058/mercurial-eclipse-plugin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key part of the error message is "requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jface.text 3.11.0'".

This is saying that at least version 3.11.0 of the org.eclipse.jface.text plugin is required. This version of the plugin was first released in Eclipse Neon (4.6) - so your Eclipse Luna is too old. You will need to move to a newer version of Eclipse to use this plugin.

Comment: Thanks, but my teammate using Luna with mercurial version 2.1.0 - but I was not sure about the correct update site for it. So will see by moving to Neon.

Comment: Neon is still old, if you are going to change you should move to a current release (Eclipse Oxygen.3a or Eclipse Photon which will be released sometime today (27/6/2018)).

Answer (score 1):

I am the current maintainer of MercurialEclipse. Like Greg said, you are facing this error message because you are trying to install the plugin on a platform with which it is not compatible.

The last couple of major releases require Neon, which is for the foreseeable future the baseline. This requirement for Neon is in turn due to a requirement for Java 8 in JavaHg *and* (if I'm not mistaken) Eclipse itself.

It is unfortunate that users cannot have a more explicit error message such as "this plugin requires Eclipse Neon or later versions".

FYI, Release Notes are published on the very website you linked to on Bitbucket. You will also find in the Wiki a [compatibility table](https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/wiki/Releases.wiki#!releases) with Mercurial proper, as well as with Eclipse. I also state the requirements or other impacting changes when I send the release announcement e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good solution, but I can see it work: just ask other guys **copy the 2.1 version files** to you, and you can place them in eclipse feature & plugin folders.

The files are: 
1. \features\mercurialeclipse_2.1.0.201304290948 
2. \plugins\com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse_2.1.0.201304290948.jar

Comment: If you are having to use some old version of eclipse in this case Spring tool suite ver 2.9.0 based on Based on Eclipse 3.7.2 - what you can do is simply download https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/eclipselabs.org/mercurialeclipse/com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse_2.1.0.201304290948.jar and place this inside `springsource/sts-2.9.0.RELEASE/plugins` and restart sts - it will work none of the above advice works due to answer from @Greg-449